# pandas.read_excel, first row values

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to get the first row from an excel file using pandas.read_excel. The issue that I have is that Pandas uses the first row values as labels for the data frame. Is there a way of having them - say - in a list?

I have tried to see if there is an option for pandas.read_excel in order to not load the first row as a label but I haven't found anything (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).

I know that I can get the same result using other libraries (i.e. xlrd, openpyxl, ..). However, if it is possible, I would like to use pandas.read_excel, in order to follow the same approach that I have used already for other sheets in the same python file and to better understand the library.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, if you have an excel spreadsheet called 'Workbook.xlsx' like:

```
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

you can read it with:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Workbook1.xlsx', header=None)
```

the `header=None` option let you skip the first line as header keeping it as it is. This returns:

```
   0  1
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for.